# Manually closing the calendar primereact

Tags: reactjs, typescript, primereact

I'm using **primereact version 6.2.1**, While using the calendar from primereact *i have enabled the option for **showTime***. This brings up a datePicker with an overlay blocking out the rest of the webpage. All this works fine. Except after a date and time are picked the only way to close the datePicker is to click somewhere else on the  browser. Is there a way to close it manually ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

import { Calendar } from 'primereact/calendar';

    const CustomCalendar = (props) => {
     const cal = useRef(null);
      const handleClose = () => {
        cal.current.hideOverlay()
        // if you're using touchUI option you have to hade it also ;)
        cal.current.touchUIMask.style.display = "none";
      };
      return  <Calendar
        ref={cal}
        {...props}
        footerTemplate={(e) => <div className='footer-calendar'><button onClick={handleClose}>Done</button></div>}
      />
    }
```

> You can close overlay manually using ref, you can check this link
> [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cannon-eptbrw?file=/src/demo/CalendarDemo.js)
>
> or check the github link for more options
> [github](https://github.com/melloware/primereact/blob/8e459797ee6a74766b195274979eb84a9b2282f0/components/lib/calendar/Calendar.d.ts#L154)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you get a ref to your `Calendar` you can call `calendarRef.current.hideOverlay();`

I also opened this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/2685

Submitted this PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/pull/2687

Answer (score 0):

There is a property for this scenario. When combined with the `showTime`, the `hideOnDateTimeSelect` will hide the overlay on a date selection. So, make sure `hideOnDateTimeSelect` is set to true and you will have the wanted behavior without dealing with refs

From the docs: https://primereact.org/calendar/#api.Calendar.props.hideOnDateTimeSelect